# Does the wording need changing on "whats meta" page in non-MSE help centers?

Tags: discussion, help-center, wording

The "Help Center > Our model" page on all *Meta* sites I've checked mentions "the entire network", which seems to be wrong (for any site other than MSE).

The wording is the same on:
(direct links to the "What is meta? How does it work?" pages):
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)
[English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)
[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)
And probs other/all sites, I only checked those 3.

---

**(1)**
Near the top of the help page, the 3rd bullet point:

> Meta is for...
>
> - ...Stack Exchange to communicate with the community (soliciting    feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect 
>     the **whole network**)

Discussions on policies that affect the "whole network" is for MSE, surely?

---

**(2)**
The paragraph under the bullet points:

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before,
>   avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with Stack Overflow or
>   the **Stack Exchange network**.

This may simply be intended to clarify not to discuss things which are not Stack Exchange related - asking about Yahoo answers, or Google etc.
But in that case it's not required as just before that it clearly states to avoid asking questions not relating to the [site name], which in itself covers not discussing things not "Stack Exchange" related.

I'm not being fussy, I can see why that would be "ok", but I can also see potential for confusion and people asking questions relating to the "Stack Exchange network".

Again, shouldn't questions about the Stack Exchange network as a whole be on MSE?

Comment: Having said that, and with 1999's answer (which they deleted for some bizarre reason - viewable to 10K users) TimPost's answer makes sense as an argument against my question here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251428/2632129